# How can I get the path of a newly built apk in gitlab after the code is checked in, which I need in the command 'curl' to upload it to ADF

Tags: android-testing, gitlab-ci

I wrote a python script, which uses boto3 to schedule android app UI test on ADF. My next step is to make gitlab CI work. My test suite program is Java Appium with TestNG, not integrated with the android program.

My problem now is how to get the PATH of files(apk and test.zip) in gitlab repo which needed in *curl* command to upload the newly build apk(builded after new code checked in) and my test suite.

- Actually, foremost, am I in the right track?
- Can I use curl in gitlab like that?
- If so, what's the path I could use? (if you could shortly explain the storage structure(or say namespace?) or give me some reference). Actually, is it just take the project home directory as '/'?

  - for test suite, its actually easier, if I figure out what's the path, I could just put it in the home directory.
  - for the newly built apk, I don't actually know where is it. We use the pipeline, I think the apk file is somewhere in the server. Below is the YAML snippet:

    ```
    archive_project:
    stage: archive
    script:
    - ./gradlew assembleRelease
    only:
    - master
    - search
    artifacts:
    paths:
    - main/build/outputs/
    tags:
    - android
    - gradle
    ```
- If not, how can I do that? This actually suit if I am not in the right track as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after you check in code, the runner look at the .gitlab_ci.yml, and runs following its instruction. And this process, happens in the server machine(either yours or gitlab's), so everything is basically the same as you in your computer(sure you will need the right environment, just appoint the right image or docker).

so yes, we could use 'curl' there. For the directory structure, if you have the privilege to login your server(thru ssh, for instance), you could get it easily. Or we could just explore it like what we do locally(pwd, ls, cd). So what I did is I have a script which have some "pwd, ls, cd ", and call this script from yml, then I look at the info it print to help figure out the directory structure. Then I got what I want(the path), then problem solved.

Although I didn't use [dependencies](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#dependencies), but you might want to read it to get more about how to pass artifacts between jobs.

If you are looking for this problem, hope it helps you.